# My background service gets killed and restarted with long wait despite being busy

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sqlite, service

There are many threads with similar issues and recommendations to fix. I've tried all and none works for my case except putting the service in foreground, which I do not want to do so far.

I cannot post a comment to existing threads as I don't have enough reputations and I want to question, so can't answer. This is the only choice to bring my question and look for some expert's opinions and recommendations.

Existing threads with similar issues discussed,

[Time taken for Android Service to restart after being forcibly killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534965/time-taken-for-android-service-to-restart-after-being-forcibly-killed)

[Background Service getting killed in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219249/background-service-getting-killed-in-android)

[Android: Scheduling restart of crashed service with HUGE delay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044444/android-scheduling-restart-of-crashed-service-with-huge-delay)

MY PROBLEM:

I've a **service** that starts at boot time (listening to intent `BOOT_COMPLETED`)
I start a thread that does interaction with other service through a socket and is interrupted when the service is killed `(onDestroy)`.

Using Wifi on phone, my service is never killed by android and it works as expected.

If I switch to 3G only (**At&T SIM**), My service gets killed approx. after **1800 seconds (30 minutes)** and scheduled to be restarted in approx. 3600 sec (1 hour). All this time the thread that service started is doing **SQLLite** calls and interacting with this other service.

Android thinks my service has been idle for 1800+ seconds and will kill its with long restart time.

Questions:

1. What do I need to do to tell Android ActivityManager that my service is doing work using a thread it spun, so it should not be killed. Happens only on 3G.
2. How to reduce the timer to under 20 seconds. 1 hour is just too long.
   I did used AsyncTask to spin other thread that loops for ever sleeping 1 second, but still my service gets killed.
3. How Android behavior changes when using 3G versus Wifi in determining which service to kill?

Answer (score 0):

I found that android does not support long running background services. So my service that needed to keep communicating with other services, will get killed especially on 3G/4G when network bandwidth is more restricted.

I switched back to foreground mode, works fine now. I'll still like to hear if there's a way to avoid the foreground mode on 3G/4G.